# Qt project file is not seeing an enviroment variable

Tags: linux, qt, environment-variables, qmake

I'm on a customized Linux distribution.
I'm trying to print from a **Qt** project file (using `message()` directive) an environment variable which is correctly printed in the shell. When qmake runs from the same shell instance, in the printed message is looks like the variable is empty.

I'm using the command `message($$(ENVI_VAR))` which according to the Qt website, should get the value of the variable when qmake runs (there is also the `$(ENVI_VAR)` syntax which is instead evaluated when the **Makefile** runs)

What am I missing?

Thanks

**Edit:**
Actually, not only `qmake`, but every process I run, also a script execution, can't see the environment variables. Only the shell can.

Comment: Have you tried $$system( echo $ENVI_VAR ) to obtain value of the var?

Comment: How and where do you set `ENVI_VAR`?

Comment: @vahancho in .bashrc

Comment: @N1ghtLight tried right now, but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had only defined the variables in the `.bashrc` file, but I was missing the `export`

Answer (score 0):

Usually global variables values are used as custom variables inside the `.pro` files. I'm putting here [reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#variables) to Qt doc with specific details how to do this:

"Variables can be used to store the contents of environment variables. These can be evaluated at the time that qmake is run, or included in the generated Makefile for evaluation when the project is built.

To obtain the contents of an environment value when qmakeis run, use the $$(...) operator:

```
 DESTDIR = $$(PWD)
 message(The project will be installed in $$DESTDIR)
```

In the above assignment, the value of the PWD environment variable is read when the project file is processed.

To obtain the contents of an environment value at the time when the generated Makefile is processed, use the $(...) operator:

```
 DESTDIR = $$(PWD)
 message(The project will be installed in $$DESTDIR)

 DESTDIR = $(PWD)
 message(The project will be installed in the value of PWD)
 message(when the Makefile is processed.)
```

In the above assignment, the value of PWD is read immediately when the project file is processed, but $(PWD) is assigned to DESTDIR in the generated Makefile. This makes the build process more flexible as long as the environment variable is set correctly when the Makefile is processed."

Comment: the problem ended up being linux related, and not Qt related. Sorry I do not know how to close the topic

Answer (score 0):

In `message()` need to use different notation for some reason:

```
message(DESTDIR: ($$DESTDIR))
```

I had such problem today. Solved only by looking at qmake .pro files examples in Qt [mailing list](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2015-May/017008.html). Another possible problem - [clue variables](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#variables):

```
# ${VAR} notation allows to append the contents of the variable to another value
# without separating the two with a space
isEmpty(DESTDIR): DESTDIR = $${IDE_BUILD_TREE}/lib/qtcreator/plugins
```

Without such notation I got empty `DESTDIR` variable.